# Create event does not acknowledge timezone passed in

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using Microsoft Graph to create an `event`. Everything is working except it always creates the event in UTC. I am following the examples from the documentation, but still no luck.

Here is the body of the post:

```json
{
    "subject": "My event",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-11-03T04:14:31.883Z",
        "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-11-10T05:14:31.883Z",
        "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
    }
}
```

and here is the response:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('...')/events/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"1OZnj8JcDU6yRK1K4rYSNQABJ3X/lw==\"",
    "id": "...",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-11-03T04:15:13.7075368Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-11-03T04:15:13.7231636Z",
    "changeKey": "1OZnj8JcDU6yRK1K4rYSNQABJ3X/lw==",
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
    "iCalUId": "...",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": true,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "My event",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": "...",
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": ""
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-11-03T04:14:31.8830000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-11-10T05:14:31.8830000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `start` and `end` properties represent [`dateTimeTimeZone` type](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/datetimetimezone) and `DateTime` property expect the value to be specified in `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm[:ss[.fffffff]]` format (see [Edm.DateTime type](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/) description for more details).

In your example `Z` needs to be omitted from `2017-11-10T05:14:31.883Z` since ['Z' is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), that's the reason why `timeZone` property is getting ignored.

For example:

```
{
  "subject": "My event",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-11-03T04:14:31.8830000",
    "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-11-10T05:14:31.8830000",
    "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
  }
}
```

Comment: However, it would be nice to get error 400 when sending a request that contains ambiguous data. This behaviour (ignoring timezone in case of "Z") is not described I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippets works.

```
invite.Start.TimeZone = eventInvite.TimeZone;
invite.Start.DateTime =  eventInvite.StartDateTime.LocalDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
invite.End.TimeZone = eventInvite.TimeZone;
invite.End.DateTime = eventInvite.EndDateTime.LocalDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```